# Apart from Campfire what other furniture can I use to cook raw food?

Tags: starbound

I'm looking for a more indoor solution for my cooking needs, the campfire looks a little weird in the middle of the spaceship.

[image: spacefire]

Comment: http://starbounder.org/Cooking#Cooking_Stations

Comment: @Aequitas Nice! I don't know why I couldn't find it. The structure of the 3 wiki sites seems to be a bit of a mess now. Why don't you write that in an answer ?

Comment: @Paul because we don't want answers on stackexchange which are just a link to an answer. We want answers on the site itself.

Comment: Also, the article posted by Aequitas links several items which are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternative cooking stations available. Unfortunately none of them can be crafted. You will need a bit of luck to find one at the stage of the game where you currently appear to be. The items with "*" are items I would personally consider a proper match for the aesthetics of the Human ship:

- Barrel fire (found in USCM Prisons and Bandit camps)
- Basic stove* (found in USCM Bunker)
- Cabin Oven
- Large Glitch Cooking Pot (found in Glitch villages and castles)
- Primitive Stove (found in Floran villages)
- Retro Oven* (I am not sure if it can be found, but the technical name for it is `apexoven`, implying it might appear in Apex facilities)
- Rustic Oven
- Stout Avian Oven (found in Avian villages)

Some of these items are also occasionally available from the Frögg Furniture store in the Outpost.

Source: http://starbounder.org/Cooking#Cooking_Stations and linked articles